# Visual studio additional Library Directories

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

In Visual Studio 2010 in Additional Library Directories what does the following mean?

```
${JOHN_DOE}\libs
```

Does it mean search for `libs` folder in `JOHN_DOE` folder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Linker will search in `JOHN_DOE` before it searches the path specified in the LIB environment option.

Use the `/LIBPATH` option to override the environment library path. The linker will first search in the path specified by this option, and then search in the path specified in the LIB environment variable. You can specify only one directory for each /LIBPATH option you enter. If you want to specify more than one directory, you must specify multiple /LIBPATH options. The linker will then search the specified directories in order.

For more details, check [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1xhzskbe.aspx)